# How to install android side by side with Windows Phone?

Tags: lumia, android

I want to install Android OS on my Lumia 540. Since Windows phone is basically built on NT kernel, shouldn't there be a way to dual boot two mobile OSes ?

Has someone tried and found an answer?

Comment: WP8.0 and higher is built on NT, yes (WP7.x used a modified CE kernel), but the phone's firmware bootloader - which is responsible for loading the OS bootloader - contains Secure Boot restrictions. Only OS loaders signed with Microsoft's key are allowed to run on most WP devices. To install Android (or any other Linux), you'd need to unlock the bootloader (disable Secure Boot or add your own key), and even then you wouldn't have the right drivers for the hardware. You can look for bootloader unlocks - some phones have them - but it won't make Android just work even if you can install it.

Comment: why is this a comment and not an answer? ;-)